# UI text not Showing in Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]
The UI Only Text is not showing in Unity Version 2021.2.14f1.

Comment: Check Legacy, they moved it there.

Comment: Use text mesh pro instead, any way better than text